# How can I install a more modern version of GNU utils (coreutils) on Debian Linux with no admin rights?

Tags: linux, debian, coreutils

I would like to install a more modern version of GNU utils (coreutils) on a debian linux system where I have no admin rights. Is there a way to do that?

The rationale is that I need a more modern version to the one installed in the system where I intend to run my analysis. I am trying to use "sort -R" or "shuf" to randomize lines in a big text file.

Comment: No way. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The rationale is that I need a more modern version to the one installed in the system where I intend to run my analysis. I am trying to use "sort -R" or "shuf" to randomize lines in a big text file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't install them in the sense that they override the existing ones for all users of the system, but you can compile and install them in your home directory and configure your `PATH` such that they are ran instead of the system ones.

To do so, download the latest version of coreutils from the [GNU web site](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). Then, extract the archive and `cd` into it, and run the following commands to compile and install it.  Note the `--prefix` switch that lets you configure the directory you want it to install in.

```
./configure --prefix=/home/avilella/coreutils/
make
make install
```

Most Debian systems are configured to automatically add `~/bin` to your PATH.  If that's the case, you can copy the utilities to that directory.  However, it may not be configured to run executables from that directory *before* searching system directories, or you may prefer to keep them in their own directory.  In that case, you will need to edit your `~/.profile` to search that directory before searching the system ones.  To do so, add a line like this:

```
PATH="$HOME/coreutils/bin:$PATH"
```

If you'd prefer not to compile them, you could also extract them from a newer Debian package by using `ar vx` on the `.deb` file to output a `data.tar.gz` tarball with the package contents.  But newer packages might require newer libraries not present on your system.

Comment: In `PATH=...`, double or no quotes must be used. Using single quotes will cause the literal `$HOME` and `$PATH` to be inserted, rather than their values.

Comment: @grawity:  Wow, what a dumb mistake, especially considering that I have been brain damaged by PHP's similar string handling for ages now.  Thanks for the fix!